# F#: Is there a function that can be used in place of the dot operator?

Tags: f#

In F# one comes across this sort of thing:

```
let p = Earth().GetCountry1().GetPopulation()
```

Sometimes I find myself wanting to separate the argument from the function as is usually done in F#:

```
let p = ((Earth ()).GetCountry1 ()).GetPopulation ()
```

which requires many parentheses. Is there a function, or can someone think of one, which can be used in place of the dot operator, which facilitates a more elegant way of maintaining the space between function and argument -- something like this?

```
let dot method arg obj = obj.method arg
let p = Earth () |> dot GetCountry1 () |> dot GetPopulation ()
```

(My `dot` causes a compiler error.)

Comment: Hm, that looks like a quite horrible mix (IMHO) of OO and functional style. Why define getCountry1 and getPopulation as class methods if you prefer to pipe function results?

Comment: @Guran I might be using a library, for example.

Comment: Certainly, but in that case I would simply use your original syntax instead of cramming it into a pipng pattern. (a matter of taste, of course). You can pipe to a fun like in the answer below, but...

Comment: @Guran My original syntax does not address the question.

Comment: No it doesn't. But in my eyes (and I definitely prefer functional style in F#) it is way clearer than a "dot function". Not trying to bash you here, sorry if it seemed so.

Comment: @Guran That's okay, it didn't seem so. I just have a specific question, that's all. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The original code is perfectly idiomatic F#. There's no need to change it.

However, sometimes you have an F# function pipeline and you need to call a method in the middle of it. The neatest way to do this is with a lambda:

```ml
aValue
|> aFunction parameter
|> anotherFunction
|> fun x -> x.Method()
|> oneLastFunction
```

The function you're trying to write is not possible in a statically typed language. This would need to be added as a language feature, or you can simply use a lambda as shown above.

Comment: My question is not about idiomatic F#. But I suppose `Earth () |> fun e -> e.GetCountry1 () |> fun c -> c.GetPopulation ()` is close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is an approved language request that would make this slightly more concise. https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506

Answer (score 3):

First off, F# is a multi-paradigm language, so writing code in an OOP style is perfectly valid. If you are consuming C# libraries, this is very common.

I would suggest using the OOP-style (no space before arguments) for the OOP-style code and the functional-style (space after arguments) for the functional-style code.

There is no built-in mechanism for piping members in F#. This could be enabled in the future with [the short-hand accessor suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506) or [the lenses suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/379).

For now, the quickest solution for the functional-style is to write an anonymous function:

```ml
let p = 
  Earth ()
  |> fun x -> x.getCountry1 ()
  |> fun x -> x.getPopulation ()
```

If you do this frequently, it might be best to write a collection of helper functions:

```ml
let country1 x = 
  x.getCountry1 ()

let population x = 
  x.getPopulation ()

let p = 
  Earth ()
  |> country1
  |> population
```

You could probably implement your `dot` function using reflection but that would have a run-time overhead, which is probably not worth it.